# Delete after select not working

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, select, phpmyadmin

In this website I am developing a genuine product code verification system, so when user inserts a code in form this will show them whether their product is genuine or not, but users can verify their product only once after that their code will be deleted from database.  I have successfully created "search" part.  When I am trying to delete that same record its not working. I want to do delete just after select.

Please look this code and suggest me how to delete that record.
I am not a pro just a beginner.

```
<?php
$produt_code = $_GET["product_code"];

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "#";
$password   = "#";
$dbname     = "#";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql    = "SELECT product_code FROM product_verify WHERE product_code=" . $_GET["product_code"];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<font color="green"><h3>Congratulations!! You Have Genuine Product</h3></font>';

    }
} else {
    echo '<font color="red"><h3>Sorry!! You Dont Have A Genuine Product.</h3></font><br><font color="red"><h3>NOTE:</h3></font><font color="red"><h3>1.Please check for spelling mistakes and try again.</h3></font><font color="red"><h3>2.May be this product code is already verified.</h3></font>';

}
?>
```

i am using this code just after select statement

```
$sql2 = "DELETE FROM product_code WHERE product_code=" . $_GET["product_code"];
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
```

but its not deleting that record i tried posting this same code after while statement but no use
tried this also

```
mysqli_query = "SELECT city_name,product_code FROM code_verify WHERE product_code=" . $_GET["product_code"];
    $query = mysql_affected_rows();
       if($query > 0)
       {
       $sql = "DELETE FROM product_code WHERE product_code=" . $_GET["product_code"];
```

but non of this is working
also tried another php for delete in same file

Comment: Can you post the code which you are using to try to delete the product code.  If this piece of code it working, we won't know what's wrong with the delete code until we can see it

Comment: Write code for me questions are not well received, you might want to at least try something in that direction

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place the deletion query inside the while:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<font color="green"><h3>Congratulations!! You Have Genuine Product</h3></font>';
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM product_code WHERE product_code=".$_GET['product_code'];
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    }
```

This way you will execute the query only when you are sure that the user will get the feedback.

Comment: Try to put your query inside an if statement to see what error it drops: if(!$results2){echo mysqli_error($conn)}

Comment: its working thanks                                                                                     $sql2 = "DELETE FROM product_verify WHERE  product_code=".$_GET['product_code'];
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        if(!$results2){
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
        }

Answer (score 0):

first thing don't  use "query"."variable" in PHP tag so remove that and replace this

`$sql    = "SELECT product_code FROM product_verify WHERE product_code = $_GET["product_code"]";`

second thing remove single quotes from out sides of echo and use "" Double quotes outer sides and use single quotes '' inside the double quotes.

echo "

#### Congratulations!! You Have Genuine Product

";

Comment: Neither of the things you mention attempt to answer the question of the delete issue

Comment: for delete query use this sql query  `$sql = delete From product_verify where product_code = $_GET['product_code'] ";`

Comment: I suggest using filtering and escaping of $_GET['product_code'] value to avoid SQL Injections attacks,